# Can't open generated .mht file from Tomcat webserver

Tags: java, security, tomcat, cpu-word

I'm generating a custom Word documents in my web application using the .mhtml format.  Previously this was working fine. I assemble the document and write it to a directory then give a link to the file (with a .doc extension).  Recently my template has changed to include embedded images.  Now when I attempt to save and open a file from the web app, Word refuses to open it.  It just shows a message "Cannot open file .." with the path.  When you view the help it says something about lack of memory which is bogus.

When I open the exact same file from my localhost server it works fine.  The two files (local and production) are identical.  I've tried adding the site as a Trusted Site - no luck.

Any ideas?
Jeff

Comment: Also when I save the file and view it's properties it has a security message saying it was from an unknown source and may be a security threat.  There is an Unblock button.  Even after clicking Unblock it still won't open.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the webserver does not annotate with a correct mimetype.

Is the downloaded file identical with the one present in the webserver?  Do a byte-wise comparison.

Also try other browsers to see.  IE has some quirks.

Comment: Yes, the files are identical.  I've tried it in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Solved issue by switching to plain HTML format with images as external links.